# How is this E-R diagram of an identifying relationship's mapping cardinality correct?

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

[image: E-R Diagram of an Identifying Relationship]
[image]
According to textbook Database System Concepts,"The identifying relationship is many-to-one from the weak entity set to the identifying entity set, and the participation of the weak entity set in the relationship is total." In the same book is an E-R diagram of an identifying relationship that appears to me to be conflicting with the first half of the above statement. The mapping cardinality of the identifying relationship from the weak to identifying entity set of the diagram appears to be many-to-many.

Am I misunderstanding the diagram or statement?

Comment: In that diagram, what do you think are the weak entity, the identifying entity, and the cardinality of the relationship?

Comment: Good question. I updated the question to include a legend.

Comment: - weak entity: payments (according to textbook)  
- identifying entity: policy   
- cardinality: many-to-one  

From the textbook, "Payments are modeled as weak entities since they are related to a specific policy."

Although, I just noticed that that discriminating attribute of weak entity set premium_payment is not underscored with dash lines which also contradicts the book.